# Libreoffice base report's total

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-base

I've found a lot of info about how to add "total" row to report, but none of them worked as needed. As for the moment I have a report, made of query and additional query, calculating only totals.

the report shows the first query's values as a table. I have added new form, linked to second query, added formatted text box, showing the totals. I want the total field right under the last line in the table, so I added new row to report's table and added field there. When generated, the data from the first query overwrites that column (and messing the formatting). If I add it just right under the table (not inside it) - the field hasn't been shown (I presume it's area 've been overwritten by table - Doesn't matter is I anchor it as character or by paragraph).
If I add the field somewhere far under the table - that works, but it's very unhandy to have report's table and far under it - totals.

How can I put the field under the table? When I tried to put the table in another two-rows table (one is for first query, one is for totals) - Base crashes.

[image]

Comment: I think you are asking a legitimate question but it is hard for me to understand.  Please edit your question to provide an SQL view of the different queries involved.  It may also help if you break down your question into smaller paragraphs.  Also you mentioned a form, but I think the important part of your question is only about one report plus queries.  If so then maybe you could remove discussion of forms.

Comment: There is no problem with queries. They return what they should return. The form I'm talking about is this: http://s8.postimg.org/nowaod4zp/Screenshot_04_12_2015_23_23_10.png

The question is: how to place field right under the table? When "rendered" the form covers the field if it has been put there the usual way.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your question without an idea of what the queries look like.  Please show an SQL view of the queries.  You mentioned a first and second query.  How are they related?  And how related to a form?  And a report?  It would help to have more clear details.

Comment: I have no idea how this will help you, but if you insist: http://pastebin.com/q7jyWjrb Report has been made via wizard based on the first query, I added second "form" and the field based on the second query manually after.

Comment: So is your question only about the second query and its report?  In stackoverflow when you ask a question it is important to simplify the problem, so make simpler queries and a report (or form?) that still shows the problem.

Comment: My question is only about how to place that goddamn field to be exactly under the last row.

Comment: A report can only be based on one query, as you have found.  You say you have found directions on getting a total included in a report but weren't able to get them to work in your particular case.  Would you post a link to one such set of directions and share exactly which step you are stuck on?

Comment: @Lyrl, create reort via wizard, based on any query. Create query with one output column. Open report in editor, Open form navigator, add new form and select your second query in its attributes. Add fieldbox to the report, it will be attached to the second query in form navigator. Select output column in box's attributes. http://s8.postimg.org/nowaod4zp/Screenshot_04_12_2015_23_23_10.png Now you have report based on two queries. The thing I want is to place the field right after the table, attaching it to the table's end. As for the moment the table covers it when it's too close, or it's vise v

Comment: I see from the screenshot you are using the old kind of report, and not the Oracle Report Builder that is integrated into newer versions of LibreOffice, or available as an extension for OpenOffice or old versions of LibreOffice.  I was never able to get that kind of report to work for me.  I unfortunately do not have any advice for your current kind of report, but believe you will find more resources if you switch to the ORB kind of report.